# Sum Data In Codeigniter Dynamic Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, sum, append

I have an "add more" function within a form in codeigniter. I'd simply like to show a running total as people add in data in each added row.

When you add numbers into the first row everything works correctly and the number I typed shows up in the "TOTALS" cell.

My issue is that when I click "add more" and add data into additional rows the formula does not add up the data from all the rows.

HOWEVER ... let's say I click "add more" 3 times (which gives me a total of 4 rows), if I put data into the new rows FIRST ...and then add data into the top (original) row last ...THEN the formula will add the data of all the cells from that column.

***SAMPLE ADD MORE FORM***

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| SUBCONTRACTOR | TOTAL TESTS | TOTAL DIAGNOSED | ADD MORE |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Entry 1       |    5        |      9          |  remove  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Entry 2       |    3        |      1          |  remove  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Entry 3       |    2        |      4          |  remove  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| TOTAL         |    10       |      14         |  remove  |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ADD COLUMNS SCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('[id^=nonclinsub]').on('keyup',function() {
            var total = 0;

            $('[id^=nonclinsub]').each(function(index){

                total += parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
            });
            
            var totalAll = $('#amt_nonclinsub_1').val(total.toFixed(0));
            
});

$('[id^=subdx]').on('keyup',function() {
            var total = 0;

            $('[id^=subdx]').each(function(index){

                total += parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
            });
            
            var totalAll = $('#amt_subdx_2').val(total.toFixed(0));
            
});


});
</script>
```

***ADD MORE HTML & SCRIPT***

```
<!--SUBCONTRACTOR NON-CLINICAL SECTION -->


<h2 class="page-header">1b. Non-Clinical Subcontractors</h2>


            <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="non_clin_sub" style="width:100%"> 
                  <tr>
                    <th width="65%">Sub-Contractor Name</th>
                    <th width="15%">Total Tests This Month</th>
                    <th width="15%">Total Diagnosed</th>
                    <th width="5%"> &nbsp; </th>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <!-- APPEND -->
                    <tr id="non_clin_calc">  
                          
                          
                        <td><select name="ncs[0][sub_name]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
                            <option value="NA">Choose</option>
                          
                          
        <?php $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>
        <?php if($user_id == '3' || $user_id == '4' || $user_id == '48' || $user_id == '49' || $user_id == '50' || $user_id == '67'):?>
                          
                            <?php foreach($subcontractors_all as $subcontractor) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?></option>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
                      
      <?php else:?>
                            <?php foreach($subcontractors as $subcontractor) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?></option>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif;?>
                          </select></td>

      
                      
                      
                        <td><input type="number" id="nonclinsub[0]_1" name="ncs[0][sub_tests]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list amount_non_clin"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="subdx[0]_1" name="ncs[0][sub_dx]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list amount_non_clin_dx"  /></td>
                      
                        <td><button type="button" name="add_ncs" id="add_ncs" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                    </tr>  
                  <!-- APPEND -->
                  
                </table>  
              
              <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                  
                  
                    <tr>
                         <td width="64%">
                           <strong><span class="form-control name_list">TOTAL</span></strong>
                         </td>
                      
                         <td width="15%">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control name_list" value="0" name="total_ncs_1" id="amt_nonclinsub_1" readonly="readonly">
                         </td>
                      
                        <td width="15%">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control name_list" value="0" name="total_sdx_2" id="amt_subdx_2" readonly="readonly">

                        </td>
                        
                      <td width="6%"><span class="form-control name_list"> &nbsp; </span></td> 
                      
                    </tr>
              </table>
              
            </div>
                  <!-- END DIV CLASS TABLE RESPONSIVE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      var i=1;  
   
      $('#add_ncs').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#non_clin_sub').append('<tr id="add_ncs-row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><select name="ncs['+i+'][sub_name]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" ><option value="NA">Choose</option><?php $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?><?php if($user_id == '3' || $user_id == '4' || $user_id == '48' || $user_id == '49' || $user_id == '50' || $user_id == '67'):?><?php foreach($subcontractors_all as $subcontractor) : ?><option value="<?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?><?php else:?><?php foreach($subcontractors as $subcontractor) : ?><option value="<?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?><?php endif;?></select></td> <td><input type="number" id="nonclinsub['+i+']_1" name="ncs['+i+'][sub_tests]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list amount_non_clin"  /></td> <td><input type="number" id="subdx['+i+']_1" name="ncs['+i+'][sub_dx]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list amount_non_clin_dx"  /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td> </tr>');  
      });
  
      $(document).on('click', '#non_clin_sub .btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#add_ncs-row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: That's not CodeIgniter, that's more javascript.  Change your tags so they can see it.

Comment: This is in a codeigniter form because my ```ncs[0][sub_name]``` values as well as my ```add_ncs-row'+i+'``` dynamically appended "add more" values are being passed to my controller file from the form as the user adds more rows.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Put the event on a static container, like the table `#non_clin_sub`, and delegate it to any matching selectors like `[id^=nonclinsub]`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#non_clin_sub').on('keyup', '[id^=nonclinsub]', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[id^=nonclinsub]').each(function(index) {
     total += parseFloat($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0);
    });
    $('#amt_nonclinsub_1').val(total.toFixed(0));
  });

  $('#non_clin_sub').on('keyup', '[id^=subdx]', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[id^=subdx]').each(function(index) {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0);
    });
    $('#amt_subdx_2').val(total.toFixed(0));
  });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work. That may work for static fields but it doesn't work for dynamic fields for some reason.

Comment: What doens't work? I just removed the `var totalAll =` because setting a input value in jquery doesn't return anything. But what doesn't actually work?

Comment: So instead of ```var total = 0;``` I need to put ```var totalAll = 0:``` ?